# How to create default subfolders using procmail with Maildir (and postfix) that work with MUA's?

Tags: procmail, maildir

I have a procmail setup and want to have a Spam folder that works with MUA's.

I found this tutorial http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-move-spam-mail-to-spam-folder/ but it doesn't work as expected.

I want to be able to open a mail client and see the Spam folder to deduce whether or not the messages are actually spam. How do I do this having a "default" Spam folder setup that can be read/accessed from mail clients like Thunderbird and Roundcube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original configuration was this (`/etc/procmailrc`):

```
# Move to spam folder
:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.Spam
```

The working configuration is:

```
# Move to spam folder
:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.Spam/
```

Note, this is also a dovecot configuration. Once I did this MUA's are able to access the newly created folders.

More info: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/procmail

Answer (score 0):

You also have to make sure that the user is subscribed to the Spam folder, otherwise he will not see the folder in his MUA.

I use Courier and maildrop with [this script](http://gogs.info/books/debian-mail/chunked/utilities.html#utilities.maildrop) that checks folder subscription in courierimapsubscribed file that Courier uses to keep track of subscribed folders. I guess there should be something similar for Dovecot and procmail.